# Create alphabet tracing worksheet

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, alphabet

I want to reproduce these pages in order to teach children **all the letters** of the alphabet, 
I wonder if I could produce it in Latex instead of ordering a notebook 
on the internet ?

Many thanks for your help.

[image: Wanted worksheet]

Comment: With reference to the terms of [this figure](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Typography_Line_Terms.svg), you could draw lines corresponding to baseline, x-height, descent, ascent for each character. You may find [useful hints](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203880/align-tikz-arrow-with-x-height-character) on x-height. I'm sorry I don't have the time and experience necessary to formalize an answer in short; I just liked the question and thought this could be a way for a font family/size.. independent solution. PS>Colors are really important for children of each age.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460836/custom-line-cap-to-simulate-inked-line-in-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1) I added the lower-case characters. Looking at the question it seems to me that the dashed red line is not always in the middle. Rather, e.g. in the case of the letter `A` it seems to be where the horizontal line of the `A` is. One can account for this in a straight-forward way: when defining the pics, add a coordinate at the vertical position, called `(-mid)` in the following. If you call the pic `A`, `pic(A){A}`, then the coordinate will have the name `(A-mid)`. This allows us to place the red line differently depending on the specifics of the character.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
 \pgfdeclarelayer{background} 
 \pgfdeclarelayer{behind} 
 \pgfdeclarelayer{foreground} 
 \pgfsetlayers{behind,background,main,foreground}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460842/121799
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  A/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,-0.5) -- (0.3,0.4) -- (0.6,-0.5);
  \draw[pic actions](0.1,1/3-0.45) -- coordinate(-mid)
  (0.5,1/3-0.45);
  \path (0.7,0);}},
  B/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45)
  to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2.5]  (0,0) coordinate(-mid)  to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3] cycle;}},
  C/.style={code={\draw[pic actions]
   (0,0) to[out=90,in=110,looseness=2]  (0.5,0.25);
   \draw[pic actions](0,0) coordinate(-mid) to[out=-90,in=-110,looseness=2]  (0.5,-0.25);
   \path (0.7,0);}},
  D/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0,0.45) 
  to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2.25]   cycle;
  \path (0.7,0);}},
  E/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0.5,-0.45) --(0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45)  -- (0.5,0.45);
  \draw[pic actions] (0,0) -- coordinate(-mid) (0.5,0);
  \path (0.7,0);}},
  F/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45)  -- (0.5,0.45);
  \draw[pic actions] (0,0) -- coordinate(-mid) (0.5,0);
  \path (0.7,0);}},
  G/.style={code={\draw[pic actions]
   (0,0) to[out=90,in=110,looseness=2]  (0.5,0.25);
   \draw[pic actions] (0,0) coordinate(-mid) to[out=-90,in=-110,looseness=2]  
   (0.5,-0.25);
   \draw[pic actions] (0.54,-0.25) to (0.3,-0.25);
   \path (0.7,0);}},
  H/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5);  
  \draw[pic actions] (0.5,-0.5) -- (0.5,0.5);
  \draw[pic actions] (0,0) -- coordinate(-mid) (0.5,0);
  \path (0.7,0);}},
  I/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0,0.45);
  \path (0.25,0);}},
  J/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0.2,0.45) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0.2,-0.35) to[out=-90,in=0]
  (0.1,-0.45) to[out=180,in=-90] (0,-0.35);
  \path (0.45,0);}},
  K/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45); 
  \draw[pic actions] (0.4,0.45) -- (0.02,0)coordinate(-mid) --  (0.4,-0.45);
  \path (0.6,0);}},
  L/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,0.5) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0,-0.45) -- (0.4,-0.45);
  \path (0.6,0);}},
  M/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0,0.45) -- 
  (0.3,0.25) -- (0.6,0.45) -- (0.6,-0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  N/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0,0.45) -- (0.6,-0.4) --
  (0.6,0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  O/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.3,0)coordinate(-mid) circle(0.3 and 0.48);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  P/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid)(0,0.45) 
  to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2.5]  (0,0);
  \path (0.6,0);}},
  Q/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0.3,0) coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) circle(0.3 and 0.48);
  \draw[pic actions](0.35,-0.25) -- (0.6,-0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  R/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,-0.45) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0,0.45) 
  to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2.5]  (0.05,0) -- (0.4,-0.45);
  \path (0.6,0);}},
  S/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.5,0.4)  
  to[out=160,in=165,looseness=2]  (0.3,0)  coordinate(-mid)
  to[out=-15,in=-20,looseness=2] (0.1,-0.4);
  \path (0.65,0);}},
  T/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.35,-0.45) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0.35,0.45) (0,0.45) -- (0.7,0.45);
  \path (0.85,0);}},
  U/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0.5) -- (0,0)coordinate(-mid) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=2.5]
  (0.6,0) -- (0.6,0.5);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  V/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0.5) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0.3,-0.4) -- (0.6,0.5);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  W/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0.45) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0.3,-0.4) -- (0.45,-0.1)
  -- (0.6,-0.4) -- (0.9,0.45);
  \path (1.1,0);}},
  X/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,0.45) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0.6,-0.45);
   \draw[pic actions] (0.6,0.45)
  -- (0,-0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  Y/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,0.45) -- (0.3,0) coordinate(-mid);  
  \draw[pic actions] (0.6,0.45)
  -- (0,-0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  Z/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0.45) --(0.6,0.45) 
  -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0,-0.45)  
  -- (0.6,-0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  space/.style={code={\path (0,0) (0.2,0);}},
  a/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.2,-0.25) circle[x radius=0.2,y radius=0.25];
    \draw[pic actions] (0.4,-0.5) -- (0.4,0) coordinate(-mid);}},
  b/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.2,-0.25) circle[x radius=0.2,y radius=0.25];
    \draw[pic actions] (0,-0.5) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid)(0,0.5);}},
  c/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.2,-0.25)+ (40:0.2 and 0.25) arc[start angle=40,
    end angle=320,x radius=0.2,y radius=0.25];
    \path (0.2,0) coordinate(-mid);}},
  d/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.2,-0.25) circle[x radius=0.2,y radius=0.25];
    \draw[pic actions] (0.4,-0.5) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid)(0.4,0.5);}},
  e/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.25) -- (0.4,-0.25) arc[start angle=0,
    end angle=320,x radius=0.2,y radius=0.25];
    \path (0.2,0) coordinate(-mid);}},
  f/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.2,-0.5)
  -- (0.2,0.3) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=0.15];
  \draw[pic actions] (0,0) -- (0.4,0) coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid);}},
  g/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.2,-0.25) circle[x radius=0.2,y radius=0.25];
    \draw[pic actions] (0.4,0) coordinate(-mid)-- (0.4,-0.6)
    arc[start angle=0,end angle=-140,radius=0.2];}},
  h/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.5)--(0,0.4);
    \draw[pic actions] (0,-0.2) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=0.2]
     coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid)-- (0.4,-0.5);}},
  i/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.1)coordinate(-mid); 
  \fill (0,0.25) circle[radius=0.05];}},
  j/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.6) arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,
  radius=0.1] -- (0.2,0.1)coordinate(-mid); 
  \fill (0.2,0.25) circle[radius=0.05];}},
  k/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.4);
  \draw[pic actions](0.2,-0.5) -- (0,-0.05)coordinate(-mid) -- (0.2,0.4);}},
  l/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.5) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid) (0,0.4);}},
  m/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0) coordinate(-mid);
   \draw[pic actions] (0,-0.2) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=0.2]
     -- (0.4,-0.5);
     \draw[pic actions] (0.4,-0.2) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=0.2] -- (0.8,-0.5);}},
  n/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0) coordinate(-mid);
   \draw[pic actions] (0,-0.2) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=0.2]
     -- (0.4,-0.5);}},
  o/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.2,-0.25) circle[x radius=0.2,y radius=0.25];
  \path (0,0) coordinate(-mid);}},
  p/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.2,-0.25) circle[x radius=0.2,y radius=0.25];
  \draw[pic actions] (0,0) coordinate(-mid) -- (0,-0.8);}},
  q/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.2,-0.25) circle[x radius=0.2,y radius=0.25];
  \draw[pic actions] (0.4,0) coordinate(-mid) -- (0.4,-0.8);}},
  r/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0)coordinate(-mid);
  \draw (0,-0.1) arc[start angle=140,end angle=40,radius=0.2]; }},
  s/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.5) -- (0.2,-0.5)
  arc[start angle=-90,end angle=45,radius=0.125] 
  -- ++ (135:0.2) coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid)
  arc[start angle=225,end angle=90,radius=0.125] -- ++ (0.1,0) ;}},
  t/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.2,-0.5) -- (0.2,0.3);
  \draw[pic actions] (0,0) -- (0.4,0) coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid);}},
  u/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.4,-0.5) -- (0.4,0) coordinate(-mid);
   \draw[pic actions] (0,0) -- (0,-0.3) arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,radius=0.2];}},
  v/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0) coordinate(-mid) 
  -- (0.25,-0.5) -- (0.5,0); }},
  w/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0) coordinate(-mid) 
  -- (0.2,-0.5) -- (0.3,-0.3) -- (0.4,-0.5) -- (0.6,0);}},
  x/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0) coordinate(-mid) -- (0.4,-0.5);
  \draw[pic actions] (0,-0.5) -- (0.4,0); }},
  y/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0) coordinate(-mid)  -- (0.25,-0.5);
   \draw[pic actions] (0.5,0) -- (0.125,-0.75);}},
  z/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0) coordinate(-mid) -- (0.3,0) -- (0,-0.5) -- (0.3,-0.5);}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=letters]
 \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {A,...,Z}
 {\draw[thick,blue] (0,-\Y-0.25) -- ++ (5,0) (0,-\Y+0.25) -- ++ (5,0);
  \path[thick] (0.5,-\Y) pic[scale=0.5](\X){\X} foreach \Z in {1,...,4}
  {(\Z+0.5,-\Y) pic[scale=0.5,dash pattern=on 1.5pt off 1.2pt]{\X}};
 \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw[red,dashed] (0,-\Y|-\X-mid) -- ++ (5,0);
 \end{pgfonlayer}
  }
 \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {a,...,z}
 {\draw[thick,blue] (6,-\Y-0.25) -- ++ (5,0) (6,-\Y+0.25) -- ++ (5,0);
  \path[thick] (6.5,-\Y) pic[scale=0.5](\X){\X} foreach \Z in {1,...,4}
  {(\Z+6.5,-\Y) pic[scale=0.5,dash pattern=on 1.5pt off 1.2pt]{\X}};
 \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw[red,dashed] (6,-\Y|-\X-mid) -- ++ (5,0);
 \end{pgfonlayer}
  }  
\end{scope}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{behind}
 \path[left color=cyan!10,right color=cyan!30] 
    (letters.south west) rectangle (letters.north east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
 \draw[line width=2mm,blue!30] ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=3mm]letters.north west) 
 -- ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=-3mm]letters.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

It is fairly obvious that there is significant room for improvement in these characters. The aim was to create some pics which are recognizable as characters, not to design a fancy new font. In the bright side, apart from adding the ink-shaped arrow heads (which explains that the pics contain more `\draw` commands than what appears necessary), the letter paths can even [be used for in decorations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475168/194703), and perhaps even more importantly subjected to nonlinear transformations, so one could project them on some 3d curved surface such as a sphere, cylinder and so on.

Here is a trivial example (with the above preamble)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path pic[xslant=0.1,thick,line cap=round]{f};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**Original answer** (in case the vertical position of the red line is wrong in the upper part): This does the uppercase letters since [someone was kind enough to provide them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460842/121799). From these you learn how one can do lower-case ones.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460842/121799
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  A/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,-0.55) -- (0.3,0.4) -- (0.6,-0.55);
  \draw[pic actions](0.1,1/3-0.45) --
  (0.5,1/3-0.45);
  \path (0.7,0);}},
  B/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45)
  to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2.5]  (0,0)  to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3] cycle;}},
  C/.style={code={\draw[pic actions]
   (0,0) to[out=90,in=110,looseness=2]  (0.5,0.25);
   \draw[pic actions](0,0) to[out=-90,in=-110,looseness=2]  (0.5,-0.25);
   \path (0.7,0);}},
  D/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45) 
  to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2.25]   cycle;
  \path (0.7,0);}},
  E/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0.5,-0.45) --(0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45)  -- (0.5,0.45);
  \draw[pic actions] (0,0) -- (0.5,0);
  \path (0.7,0);}},
  F/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45)  -- (0.5,0.45);
  \draw[pic actions] (0,0) -- (0.5,0);
  \path (0.7,0);}},
  G/.style={code={\draw[pic actions]
   (0,0) to[out=90,in=110,looseness=2]  (0.5,0.25);
   \draw[pic actions] (0,0) to[out=-90,in=-110,looseness=2]  
   (0.5,-0.25);
   \draw[pic actions] (0.54,-0.25) to (0.3,-0.25);
   \path (0.7,0);}},
  H/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5);  
  \draw[pic actions] (0.5,-0.5) -- (0.5,0.5);
  \draw[pic actions] (0,0) -- (0.5,0);
  \path (0.7,0);}},
  I/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45);
  \path (0.25,0);}},
  J/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.2,0.45) -- (0.2,-0.35) to[out=-90,in=0]
  (0.1,-0.45) to[out=180,in=-90] (0,-0.35);
  \path (0.45,0);}},
  K/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45); 
  \draw[pic actions] (0.4,0.45) -- (0.02,0) --  (0.4,-0.45);
  \path (0.6,0);}},
  L/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,0.5) -- (0,-0.45) -- (0.4,-0.45);
  \path (0.6,0);}},
  M/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45) -- 
  (0.3,0.25) -- (0.6,0.45) -- (0.6,-0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  N/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45) -- (0.6,-0.4) --
  (0.6,0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  O/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.3,0) circle(0.3 and 0.48);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  P/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45) 
  to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2.5]  (0,0);
  \path (0.6,0);}},
  Q/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0.3,0) circle(0.3 and 0.48);
  \draw[pic actions](0.35,-0.25) -- (0.6,-0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  R/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,-0.45) -- (0,0.45) 
  to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2.5]  (0.05,0) -- (0.4,-0.45);
  \path (0.6,0);}},
  S/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.5,0.4)  
  to[out=160,in=165,looseness=2]  (0.3,0)  
  to[out=-15,in=-20,looseness=2] (0.1,-0.4);
  \path (0.65,0);}},
  T/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0.35,-0.45) -- (0.35,0.45) (0,0.45) -- (0.7,0.45);
  \path (0.85,0);}},
  U/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0.5) -- (0,0) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=2.5]
  (0.6,0) -- (0.6,0.5);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  V/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0.5) -- (0.3,-0.4) -- (0.6,0.5);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  W/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0.45) -- (0.3,-0.4) -- (0.45,-0.1)
  -- (0.6,-0.4) -- (0.9,0.45);
  \path (1.1,0);}},
  X/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,0.45) -- (0.6,-0.45);
   \draw[pic actions] (0.6,0.45)
  -- (0,-0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  Y/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] 
  (0,0.45) -- (0.3,0);  
  \draw[pic actions] (0.6,0.45)
  -- (0,-0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  Z/.style={code={\draw[pic actions] (0,0.45) --(0.6,0.45) -- (0,-0.45)  
  -- (0.6,-0.45);
  \path (0.8,0);}},
  space/.style={code={\path (0,0) (0.2,0);}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=letters]
 \foreach \X [count=\Y]in {A,...,Z}
 {\draw[thick,blue] (0,-\Y-0.25) -- ++ (5,0) (0,-\Y+0.25) -- ++ (5,0);
  \draw[red,dashed] (0,-\Y) -- ++ (5,0);
  \path[thick] (0.5,-\Y) pic[scale=0.5]{\X} foreach \Z in {1,...,4}
  {(\Z+0.5,-\Y) pic[scale=0.5,densely dashed]{\X}};}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \path[left color=cyan!10,right color=cyan!30] 
    (letters.south west) rectangle (letters.north east);
 \draw[line width=2mm,blue!30] ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=3mm]letters.north west) 
 -- ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=-3mm]letters.south west);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If you change `scale=0.5` to a smaller value, the letters will become smaller, and so on.

Comment: Small quibbles: no red line on lowercase "c"; red line too low on lowercase "s"; lowercase "k" looks too much lie uppercase, upper right arm too high.  Gee, it makes me sad that apparently cursive isn't taught any more.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the heads up! And no, the cursive and so on letters are all in. I added an example: `\path pic[xslant=0.1,thick,line cap=round]{f};`. While it is hilarious to draw these glyphs with Ti*k*Z there are nevertheless some benefits like the ability to subject the characters to arbitrary (i.e. even nonlinear) transformations. Of course, `asymptote` does that with regular glyphs, but to the best of my knowledge not Ti*k*Z.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat it's is simple-but-open idea in your answer. It suggests that we can creat our own set of "handwritings". Thank you!

Comment: Many thanks @Schrödinger'scat for the huge effort. I was thinking rather of a solution which uses a particular font with the use of Tikz for dotted letters and placing the lines. That solution would allow cursive and italic/slanted letters.

Comment: @Clifford It isn't all that easy to turn a letter into a dashed letter, at least not as far as I know. For simple letters one can use clips but for the more complicate ones one essentially needs to know the outline, which Ti*k*Z does not know (see, however, [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21594)). Certainly these glyphs are far from perfect. However, they can be subjected to decorations as  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475168/194703). One *may* use these letters for defining a clipping prescription for actual fonts, but this is nontrivial.

Comment: In my opinion, I don't think you need a dashed letter. You can also changed the color of the dashed letter in to gray!20 . It's just a guideline the learn the letter. In the old days there was black and black inkt ;-)

Comment: @ArneTimperman As far as I remember I also didn't use Ti*k*Z when I was learning the alphabet. So it must indeed be possible to do without. ;-)

Comment: If you have time, would you be able to write code for the numerals 0,1,2,…9? Thanks so much!